# Dynamically created Div is returning zero height

Tags: jquery

```
//Test function
function createDiv()
{
    textContainer = $(document.createElement("div"));
    $(textContainer[0]).html(msg);
    var ctrlHeight = $(textContainer).height();
    textContainer.show();
}
```

If I check the height of the div, it returns 0 but if i check it after calling `show`, it returns the height.  Why?

Comment: element not in DOM has no measurable height...what were you expecting?

Comment: What is the question here? If the question is why the height is zero before show method is invoked, then I guess @Brandon 's answer below is the answer.

Comment: Matt@ it just an example I put here since I can not paste my code...I want to show the div on the basis of space available..and for that I need height of the div.

Comment: If that's what you want, then after creating the div, give it this style: `position: absolute; visibility: hidden; display: block;` and append it to the document.  This will make it take up space, though it will be invisible.  You can calculate its height.  If you want to "show" it after that, just remove the position and visibility styles.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers do not calculate the size of an element until it is in the document and visible

Comment: even if the parent is not visible? My case is just like this - the parent is not visible, children don't have that attribute. But children's height is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The height will not be calculated if it is not visible in browser.